# jQuery to match one element containing ALL classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following layout:

```
<p type="data" class="element section">
   <span class="element content start">Start</span>
   <span class="element content stop">Stop</span>
   <span class="element content text">Some text</span>
</p>
```

I am trying to write a function to return a reference to the span which the user can call be specifying a string, for example (bad pseudocode):

```
callMe = function(str) {
    return $node.find(str);  // $node is a reference to `p`
}
```

so I would like the user to call `callMe('element content stop')` and be returned a reference to the stop span.  `find` uses an OR condition but I need this to operate as an AND on all classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `.` for use selector class like:

```js
$node = $('p');
let callMe = function(str) {    
    return $node.find(str);  // $node is a reference to `p`
}
const span = callMe('.stop');
console.log(span[0], span[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p type="data" class="element section">
   <span class="element content start">Start</span>
   <span class="element content stop">Stop</span>
   <span class="element content text">Some text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: this works but this will match all elements inside $node having the stop class. To select the elements containing ALL classes you need .element.content.stop

Comment: OP doesn't specific if class will be unique or not.

Comment: @thchp ofc it will select all elements that has the class `stop` but in the Example given by the OP it does not matter if he write `callMe('.stop')` or `callMe('.element.content.stop')`

Comment: i was referring to the question title

Comment: @thchp still does not change anything regarding this answer, it's correct and informative and does not give misleading information

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's because the OP gave the example as `callMe('element content stop')` not `callMe('.element.content.stop')`, or `callMe('.stop')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to filter

```js
const node = document.querySelector(".element.section");
const callMe = str => {
  const classes = str.split(/\s+/);
  return [...node.querySelectorAll("span")]
    .filter(span => classes
      .filter(className => span.classList.contains(className)).length === classes.length)
}

console.log(
  callMe("element content stop")
)
```

```html
<p type="data" class="element section">
   <span class="element content start">Start</span>
   <span class="element content stop">Stop</span>
   <span class="element content text">Some text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: like that I can call this without pre-formatting, i.e. getting data from `.attr('class')` although it does seem you this is not needed since jQuery provides this for you with the proper selector.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass in a jQuery object for the node, and a selector string. Note: this method allows you to pass in a selector string representing *n* classes.
2. Create a classes variable by splitting the string on the spaces, mapping over the array and returning a new class string for each element, and then joining that mapped array back up, and use that string as the find selector.

```js
function callMe(node, selector) {

  const classes = selector
    .split(' ')
    .map(el => `.${el}`)
    .join('')
  
  return find = $(node).find(classes);

}

const spans = callMe($('p'), 'element content');
const start = callMe($('p'), 'start');
const stop = callMe($('p'), 'element content stop');

spans.each((i, v) => {
  console.log($(v).text());
});

console.log($(start).text());
console.log($(stop).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p type="data" class="element section">
  <span class="element content start">Start</span>
  <span class="element content stop">Stop</span>
  <span class="element content text">Some text</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string into an array on the space character, then loop through the array to build your selector.

```js
callMe = function(str) {
  const classes = str.split(' ');
  let classSelector;

  for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    classSelector = '.' + classes[i];
  }

  document.querySelector(classSelector).classList.add('highlight');
  // or $(classSelector).addClass('highlight')
  // but we're weaning ourselves from jQuery, right? :)
}

callMe('element content stop');
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p type="data" class="element section">
  <span class="element content start">Start</span>
  <span class="element content stop">Stop</span>
  <span class="element content text">Some text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: `str.replace(/\s+/g, ".")`?

Comment: I don't like regexes. They're very cryptic for the occasional user. This is much more readable.